# how in extjs 3 checkboxselectionmodel multiple row select with shift key while keeping the default control functionality can be done?

Tags: extjs3

how in extjs 3 checkboxselectionmodel multiple row select with shift key while keeping the default control functionality can be done? 
PLease guide me, its really urgent for me , as m doing POC. 
I tried alot, even tried the option of using jquery multiselection grid. but not able to call jquery file on checkboxselectionmodel.

Answer (score 0):

```
checkOnly : true,
```

is the config option in **checkboxselectionmodel** which will allow user to click on checkbox column only to check, and on click of row it will not select the checkbox it wil just make the row select.